# Calling a sql job from another job works only when I manually execute it, if using schedule it does not kick off the other job

Tags: sql-server

My job, **Test_Monitor Job** step 1 checks the step of another job to see if it is past step 1.  If so It executes Stored procedure  **sp_start_job**, my test job **“Test Steps Email completion”**. Step 2 of this job delays 10 min  then checks the job executed by sp in step 1, if that job is Not >= to step 1 it will send an email to me to let me know to start the job manually.

My issue is, If I execute this job manually this job works as expected.  My job **“Test_Monitor Job “** executes and step 1 and 2 are successful and my test job, **“Test Steps Email completion”** is started and is successful.

However I have this job **“Test_Monitor Job “** on a schedule to run at 6:15 AM DAILY and when I come into the office it is 8 AM, my job **“Test_Monitor Job “** is successful for both steps, BUT the job that is supposed to execute,  in step 1, **“Test Steps Email completion”** was not executed!

I have tried this on 2 different servers, what am I doing wrong? Manually execute job it works correct, let it run from time schedule it does not execute the other job…….

```
**JOB 1 Test_Monitor Job** 
/************************** TEST **********************************/
/*Step 1*/

BEGIN
/* SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
     interfering with SELECT statements.*/
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

/****CHECKING TO SEE IF STEP 1 OF ANOTHER JOB IS COMPLETE ****/
/* Body */
IF EXISTS( SELECT Job.name AS JobName,
       Job.enabled  AS ActiveStatus,
       JobStep.step_name AS JobStepName,
      JobStep.command AS JobCommand,
      CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) lastExStepDate,
      sja.last_executed_step_id AS lastStep,
      CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) DATE
 FROM   EDW1.msdb.dbo.sysjobs Job
       INNER JOIN SERVER.msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps JobStep  --table
           ON Job.job_id = JobStep.job_id
       JOIN SERVER.msdb.dbo.[sysjobactivity] sja 
    ON Job.job_id = sja.[job_id]
  WHERE job.name = 'ANOTHER_JOB' 
           AND CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
    AND sja.last_executed_step_id >1)
    
/****IF STEP 1 IS COMPLETE KICK OFF THE 'Test Steps Email completion' JOB ****/
BEGIN 
       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'Test Steps Email completion';

END

/*=============
 Restore  the count notifications
--=============*/
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END

STEP 2
/**Step 2-Need to pause for the time it is to take for the job to START step 1 OF  'Test Steps 
Email completion'  ***/
WAITFOR DELAY'00:10:00.000'  

BEGIN
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
     interfering with SELECT statements.*/
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

/****CHECKING TO SEE IF STEP 1 OF 'Test Steps Email completion' IS COMPLETE OR STARTED ****/
/* Body */
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT Job.name AS JobName,
       Job.enabled  AS ActiveStatus,
       JobStep.step_name AS JobStepName,
      JobStep.command AS JobCommand,
      CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) lastExStepDate,
      sja.last_executed_step_id AS lastStep,
      CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) DATE
 FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs Job
       INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps JobStep  --table
           ON Job.job_id = JobStep.job_id
       JOIN msdb.dbo.[sysjobactivity] sja 
    ON Job.job_id = sja.[job_id]
  WHERE job.name =  'Test Steps Email completion' 
           AND CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
            AND sja.last_executed_step_id >=1)

            
/****IF STEP 1 OF  'Test Steps Email completion' IS NOT STARTED OR COMPLETE SEND EMAIL TO 
DBA'S ****/
BEGIN 
        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
        @profile_name = 'Notifier Email Profile',  
        @recipients =  'MY_EMAIL;',
        @body = 'DBAs the Test Steps Email completion job has not started. DBAs Please log 
into Server and Manually start job Test Steps Email completion!',
        @subject = 'ALERT!! DBAs Need to Manually start Job Test Steps Email completion on 
Server  ASAP!'
;
;

END
/*=============
 Restore  the count notifications
--=============*/
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END


**JOB 2 Test Steps Email completion**
/************************** TEST **********************************/
/*STEP 1*/

EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_SQLNotify 
    @MailTo = 'EMAIL', 
    @Subject = 'Testing Solution for ANOTHER_JOB and Test_Monitor Job.', 
                @Priority = 'High'
```

Comment: FYI I have tested this with a schedule in the afternoon and it runs correctly, it does not run properly when scheduled for the morning.  So weird.  Which means to me it is not a permissions thing

Answer (score 0):

OK I have figured this out.  I had to tweek a few things, but now my job is working as I expected, for failures, notifications, scheduled time and execution of another job.

First I added to the where clause in the 1st job to bring the query down to exactly the 1 step I wanted to look at.

Second I added an ELSE statement to trigger failure if the step condition is not met and I set the advanced to try again 3 times in 15 min intervals.

Third in step 2 of the job I removed the >=1 and changed it to >1

Fourth in **Job2** I added a second Step, because production scenario has more than 1 step

Here is the New Code
**JOB 1 Test_Monitor Job**
/************************** TEST **********************************/
/*Step 1*/

```
    BEGIN
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
         interfering with SELECT statements.*/
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /****CHECKING TO SEE IF STEP 1 OF ANOTHER JOB IS COMPLETE ****/
    /* Body */
    IF EXISTS( SELECT Job.name AS JobName,
           Job.enabled  AS ActiveStatus,
           JobStep.step_name AS JobStepName,
          JobStep.command AS JobCommand,
          CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) lastExStepDate,
          sja.last_executed_step_id AS lastStep,
          CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) DATE
     FROM   EDW1.msdb.dbo.sysjobs Job
           INNER JOIN SERVER.msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps JobStep  --table
               ON Job.job_id = JobStep.job_id
           JOIN SERVER.msdb.dbo.[sysjobactivity] sja 
        ON Job.job_id = sja.[job_id]
      WHERE job.name = 'ANOTHER_JOB' 
              AND CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS 
      DATE) 
    /*BROUGHT MY QUERY DOWN TO EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR*/
              AND JobStep.step_name = 'run_Load_SG_Tables'
              AND sja.last_executed_step_id >1)

    /****IF STEP 1 IS COMPLETE KICK OFF THE 'Test Steps Email completion' JOB 
    ****/
    BEGIN 
           EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = N'Test Steps Email 
    completion';

    END
    /*ADDED ELSE TO TRIGGER FAILURE OF THE STEP IF CONDITION IS NOT MET IN THAT 
    CASE IT IS SET IN ADVANCED TO TRY AGAIN 3 TIMES IN 15 MIN INTERVALS*/
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    SELECT 1/0
    END


    /*=============
     Restore  the count notifications
    --=============*/
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END

    STEP 2
    /**Step 2-Need to pause for the time it is to take for the job to START step 
    1 OF  'Test Steps 
    Email completion'  ***/
    WAITFOR DELAY'00:10:00.000'  

    BEGIN
        /* SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
         interfering with SELECT statements.*/
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /****CHECKING TO SEE IF STEP 1 OF 'Test Steps Email completion' IS COMPLETE 
    OR STARTED ****/
    /* Body */
    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT Job.name AS JobName,
           Job.enabled  AS ActiveStatus,
           JobStep.step_name AS JobStepName,
          JobStep.command AS JobCommand,
          CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) lastExStepDate,
          sja.last_executed_step_id AS lastStep,
          CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) DATE
     FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs Job
           INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps JobStep  --table
               ON Job.job_id = JobStep.job_id
           JOIN msdb.dbo.[sysjobactivity] sja 
        ON Job.job_id = sja.[job_id]
        WHERE job.name =  'Test Steps Email completion' 
               AND CAST(sja.last_executed_step_date as date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS 
    DATE) 
       /*BROUGHT MY QUERY DOWN TO EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR*/
               AND JobStep.step_name = 'STEP 1 EMAIL'
         /*I REMOVED >= 1 AND REPLACE WITH >1 */
               AND sja.last_executed_step_id >1)

        
    /****IF STEP 1 OF  'Test Steps Email completion' IS NOT STARTED OR COMPLETE 
   SEND EMAIL TO DBA'S ****/
    BEGIN 
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
            @profile_name = 'Notifier Email Profile',  
            @recipients =  'MY_EMAIL;',
            @body = 'DBAs the Test Steps Email completion job has not started. 
   DBAs Please log into Server and Manually start job Test Steps Email 
   completion!',
            @subject = 'ALERT!! DBAs Need to Manually start Job Test Steps Email 
   completion on Server  ASAP!'
    ;
    ;

    END
    /*=============
     Restore  the count notifications
    --=============*/
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    END


    **JOB 2 Test Steps Email completion**
    /************************** TEST **********************************/
    /*STEP 1*/

    EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_SQLNotify 
        @MailTo = 'EMAIL', 
        @Subject = 'Testing Solution for ANOTHER_JOB and Test_Monitor Job.', 
        @Priority = 'High'

    /*STEP 2  ADDED THIS STEP BECAUSE PRODUCTION HAS MORE THAN 1 STEP AND NOW 
   ALL SCENARIOS WORK CORRECTLY*/
    Select 1
```